# teamcity service message - migration time?

Tags: teamcity

I currently added a process into our teamcity build pipeline to run migrations against a database.  Could anyone provide information as to how I can use service messages to record the stats on how long each migration took?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `##teamcity[<messageName> 'value']` syntax to print service messages to an output stream. As long as they appear in the build log then you'll be able to make further use of them, so you'll have to add some code to maybe output a start time and end time around each migration. e.g.

```
Console.Write("##teamcity[migration_x_started '" + DateTime.Now + "value']");
```

*run migration*

```
Console.Write("##teamcity[migration_x_ended '" + DateTime.Now + "value']");
```

You can also make use of these outputs to generate your own custom charts.

Further details can be found here - [TeamCity Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Custom+Chart)